# ¿Cómo activar el emulador de android studio sin svm?

Tags: android-studio

Me instale Android Studio, pero al intentar usar el emulador me pide que instale HAXM. Al intentar instalarlo me aparece este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Habilite la plataforma de hipervisor de windows y segui los pasos de https://github.com/intel/haxm/blob/master/docs/manual-windows.md para instalar haxm pero aun seguia saliendo el error.

Estuve buscando la solución y encontré que debía activar la virtualizacion desde la bios.

tengo un procesador Ryzen 53550H y al activar svm windows 10 no me carga y me aparece una pantalla negra. tuve que desactivar svm para que me vuelva a cargar el OS.

Estuve buscando problemas parecidos pero no encontré nada, quisiera saber si ¿hay alguna forma de usar el emulador de android studio sin habilitar la virtualización? O a que se debe que o me cargue el OS despues de activar svm

Answer (score 0):

Los procesadores AMD no soportan HAXM. Deberias usar WHPX, tal y como pone en la documentacion.

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration?hl=es-419

De todos modos, no de si ya se solucionó, pero creo que la virtualización en amd solo era posible a través de linux.

Ed: lo que puedes hacer es activar las opciones de desarrollador de tu telefono y activar la depuración USB, asi podras probar tus aplicaciones en tu movil, sin necesidad de un emulador.

Answer (score 0):

La verdad y como consejo te sugiero que si quieres hacer desarrollo móvil (Específicamente de android), pues algo que te libra de las incompatibilidades con el Hypervisor de Windows es sin duda descargar tus aplicaciones en el propio teléfono, es decir, activar la depuración USB en tu android.

Sin embargo, otra alternativa es que por ejemplo si hace desarrollo con frameworks como Flutter al menos en mi experiencia hay menos problemas

Comment: Hola y bienvenido [es.so]. Puede serte de interés, para saber como funciona el sitio, realizar el [tour] y leer [answer],